# Printing information I have stored - Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping

I am creating a news feed scraper so I can collate my favourite football teams news daily. Im an apprentice developer and I thought doing it would increase my knowledge. Just a simple thing to scan one or two sites for just headlines and return the text of the headlines. I have downloaded python, and gained a bit of knowledge around beautiful soup methods and I have managed to find a path directly to each headline on my chosen site, and I have stored these to an array

```
`page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")` //"parses" the stored data(page_html) 


`page_soup.findAll(class_="lakeside__title-text")` //finds all titles on the BBC Liverpool Sports page.

`headline1 = allHeadlines[0]` //create a single entry called "headline1"` from the first slot in our search results

'headline1.text //prints "headline1" string to show its working e.g "'What do you know about Dalglish?(my result)'"
```

But now I am puzzled as to how to create the loop needed to store the data and display.

```
for item in allHeadlines{
//something here. im a noob so all i know around this is usually item = item +1
}
print to file etc.,.
```

Any reading material for me around this topic would be greatly appreciated

Sorry for editing issues, my first ever post.

Comment: Hi. Could you please format your question where code is placed in grave accents (\`code\` quotations) and perhaps add your code in code blocks (there's a button for it when you edit the question).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming allHeadlines is list of objects ( which have method text) .
We can create a list of text from for loop for display or writing to file.

```
text_headlines = [ item.text for item in allHeadlines if item.text ] 

print(text_headlines)
```

Comment: 'page_soup.findAll("span", {"class": "lakeside__title-text"}' = this returns my values.

when I select an individual index it does this

'<span class="lakeside__title-text">What do you know about Dalglish?</span>'

So I need to be able to isolate the text